# Can't get root directory for some reason

Tags: php, require-once

I'm trying to require some files but it keeps telling me that they can't be found. The files are located in separate folders.

> index.php -> ../core/init.php -> ../library/autoload.php

http://pastebin.com/rG3bvSzn

Could anyone help me figure this out? It's been driving me insane for the past hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to include or require files, the path needs to be from the full root. Try this:

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// This is where index.php probably is

require_once($root.'sanitize.php');
require_once($root.'general.php');
?>
```

If you echo out `$root` you'll see the actual path of your files.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried that and it brings me to the absolute root of the server, I have multiple projects. This was all working before I moved the files around into seperate folders.

Comment: Well, you need to locate what folders your files are in from the root, and add that as `$root.'/folder/libaries/general.php'`. If you use ? `$root.'general.php'`, the require will assume that the files you are including are in your root folder. You need to add the folders in between.

Comment: I fixed it by moving the file calling it (init.php) theres no possible security issue with init being the root directory is there? Im trying to build an MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need full path for require scripts.

The problem is that in your autoload.php it's located in ../library/ folder and when you try an "require_once" the path starts in ../library/

The "require" start in the folder of the main script that calling the function.

/somefolder/index.php

```
require('../core/init.php');
```

/core/init.php

```
require('../library/autoload.php');
```

/library/autoload.php

```
print "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

And make your path relatively.

For PHP < 5.3.0 try,

```
$rootpath=dirname(__FILE__);

require_once($rootpath.'sanitize.php');
require_once($rootpath.'general.php');
```